# Is it possible to create indivitual folder for each user in parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform, directory

I have an application where i want to upload the maximum 2minitue length of video file to the indivitual folder for each user who login with the parse.com. Is it possible to create indivitual folder for every user in parse.com?

Please anyone can help me?

**is channel help for me in this case?**

Comment: Does parse even have a concept of folders?..As it is a cloud based back end, isn't it completed based around classes?

Comment: I agree with @JayDev parse doesn't have a concept of folders.. But you can connect a user object with a video object, thus creating a individual video for each user